# AspectJ - Trying to wrap a method that is annotated with one annotation, but not an other

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to wrap all methods annotated with @Annotation1 but not with @Annotation2.

So far I have tried 3 approaches, but all have failed. The first is with a pointcut expression. Example:

```
@Before("@annotation(Annotation1) && !@annotation(Annotation2)")
public void doTheWrapping() {
    System.out.println("Wrapped!");
}
```

This approach wraps everything annotated with Annotation1 regardless of Annotation2.

The second approach is to detect Annotation2 manually, but this does not seem to work either.

```
@Before("@annotation(Annotation1)")
public void doTheWrapping(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Method method = MethodSignature.class.cast(joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();

    if (AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(method, Annotation2.class) == null) {
        System.out.println("Wrapped!");
    }
}
```

This fails because AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(method) always return null. It doesn't seem to be aware of the annotations on the method at all.

Finally, I tried using @Pointcuts.

```
@Pointcut("execution(@Annotation1 * *(..))")
public void annotatedWithAnnotation1() {}

@Pointcut("execution(@Annotation2 * *(..))")
public void annotatedWithAnnotation2() {}

@Before("annotatedWithAnnotation1() && !annotatedWithAnnotation2()")
public void doTheWrapping() {
    System.out.println("Wrapped!");
}
```

This again, just wraps everything regardless of Annotation2.

Can anyone assist?

***SOLUTION***
Turns out the answer was really very simple. Moving the @Annotation2 to the interface rather than the implementation solved this.

Comment: Can you post a complete and reproducible example?

Comment: Your second example works fine for me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is interesting. I suspect it may be because the annotated method I am targeting is in a Spring service and the annotation is in the implementation? I don't know really, but it could be that the signature I am getting is from the declaration rather than the implementation... Just a guess.

Comment: Your best bet is to provide that MCVE.

Comment: MCVE? Is that the full example? I will... just got a deadline today. Will put together an example when I get a minute, but will be a day or two.

As for the suspicion about spring, I moved the annotation to the declaration, but it made no difference... So there goes that theory.

Answer (score 1):

Your first pointcut should work, as long as the aspect is in the same package as both annotations. Otherwise you need to specify fully qualified class names. Here is a stand-alone AspectJ example. It should be the same in Spring AOP:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Annotation1 {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Annotation2 {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    @Annotation1
    public void foo() {}

    @Annotation2
    public void bar() {}

    @Annotation1
    @Annotation2
    public void zot() {}

    public void baz() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.foo();
        application.bar();
        application.zot();
        application.bar();
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.Annotation1) && !@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.Annotation2)")
    public void doTheWrapping(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Console output for AspectJ:**

```
call(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo())
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo())
```

**Console output for Spring AOP:**

Because Spring AOP does not support `call()` pointcuts, only the `execution()` joinpoint will be intercepted as long as class `Application` is a Spring `@Component`:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo())
```